# What OST is played at the beginning of Naruto: Shippuden episode 489 after the OP?

Tags: naruto, music

I am referring to *Shikamaru's Story, A Cloud Drifting in the Silent Dark, Part 1: The State of Affairs* episode.

I played through the beginning of all the OST from the three albums of *Naruto* and the three albums of *Naruto: Shippuden* yet I can't seem to find it.

Is it from a different album or is it a part of an OST? (I haven't listened fully to most of the OST from the six albums).

Answer (score 1):

This is [Shikamaru's Lazy Cloud theme song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_XivCZhbrng). It was never officially released